# If A a compact set of real numbers. Prove that the set of all averages of two numbers in A is compact

Tags: real-analysis, compactness

I need to prove that the the set of all averages of two numbers in $A$ is compact. When $A$ itself is compact. ie {$\frac{a+b}{2}: a,b \in A$} is compact.

Whats the best way? To argue for the converging sequences a and b that converges and then $c = \frac{a + b }{2}$ is a new sequence that has a sub sequence that also converges in $A$

Or to go through the closed and bounded properties ?

Any hints?

Comment: The subsequence approach will work, if you're careful and keep things straight. You would get that there is a subsequence of a subsequence of the $c_n$ which converges. Note that it does not converge in $A$, as there is no guarantee that any of the $c_n$ are in $A$.

Comment: yes I tried a= 1, 0, 1, 0 , 1 ...  and b= 0, 1, 0, 1 ... which both do not converge however c = 1/2, 1/2, 1/2 ... converges that's why I am not sure.

Comment: Compactness does not mean that any sequence converges, but that any sequence has a _subsequence_ which converges. $0,1,0,\ldots$ has the subsequence $1,1,1,\ldots$, for instance. My point was that if $A=\{0,1\}$, then you can still have that $c_n$ converges to $\frac12\notin A$.

Answer (score 5):

Consider that map $a\colon A\times A\longrightarrow\mathbb R$ defined by $a(x,y)=\frac{x+y}2$. Then $a(A\times A)$ is compact, since $A\times A$ is compact (because we're assuming that $A$ is compact) and $a$ is continuous.